# Getting the coordinates of the camera on idle

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to get the center coordinates of the camera once the camera is on idle state after movement but its not working or logging the coordinates. Here is the code

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shifting_map)

    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}


 override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener { OnCameraIdleListener {
        val centerLatLang = mMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds.center

        Log.d("##", "lat{$centerLatLang.longitude} long{$centerLatLang.longitude}")
    } }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

setOnCameraIdleListener is a function and should use parentheses rather than brackets.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#public-final-void-setoncameraidlelistener-googlemap.oncameraidlelistener-listener

OnCameraIdleListener should require the same fix.